# How can I make rails use plaintext errors and backtraces instead of html ones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing a lot of API development and tend to interact with my rails app from a command line or network proxy.

How can I make rails use plaintext errors and backtraces instead of html ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors are printed in the server log as plaintext. If you don't have easy access to the logs, you could write a [custom exception handler](http://www.perfectline.ee/blog/custom-dynamic-error-pages-in-ruby-on-rails) which would print the error to the user in plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change your [`responds_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) handling:

```
def create
  company  = params[:person].delete(:company)
  @company = Company.find_or_create_by_name(company[:name])
  @person  = @company.people.create(params[:person])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(person_list_url) }
    format.js
    format.xml  { render :xml => @person.to_xml(:include => @company) }
  end
end
```

So if you're rendering xml, json, or text, you've got options for output, and Rails shouldn't be generating HTML error messages.